# Odoo/OpenERP: Make invisible some values inside a fields.selection

Tags: python, odoo

I have a field `selection` (`fields.selection`) with different values.

Some values are only for some automatic action. Thus,  I would like to make then "invisible" when users can select a value from this selection field. Is it possible? I try `attrs="{'invisible'}` without success.

My field:

```
'titre': fields.selection(
     (
         ('e', 'Email'),
         ('p', 'phone'),
         ('m','Post/Mail'),
         ('a', 'Automatic Action')
     ),
     'Action',
      required=True
 )
```

Here is my xml:

```
<field name="titre"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this functionality exists. Someone can correct me if I am wrong. What you could do however is use a computed select field. You may want to incorporate context variables to determine what select options need to be displayed. This can be accomplished like so.

```
@api.multi
def _compute_selection(self):
    if True:
        selection_options = [('e', 'Email'), ('p', 'phone'), ('m','Post/Mail')]
    else:
        selection_options = [('a', 'Automatic Action')]
    return selection_options

field_name = fields.Selection('_compute_selection', string="Field Name")
```

Obviously your compute function will have to flesh out the particulars. However basically you will want to compute your selection list rather than define it statically.